# Signin into electron app from browser window

Tags: angular, devise, electron, devise-token-auth, angular-token

I have electron app which uses [Angular-Token](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for Angular and [Devise Token Auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for rails backend. Oauth sign in works fine in browser using [api provided by Angular-Token](https://angular-token.gitbook.io/docs/session-management#signinoauth). It creates a new window and returns an observable and window closes after authentication is complete.

```
this.tokenService.signInOAuth(
'github'
).subscribe(
  res =>      console.log(res),
  error =>    console.log(error)
);
```

I want to implement same functionality in electron app but the problem is `this.tokenService.signInOAuth` open electron [window](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token/blob/master/projects/angular-token/src/lib/angular-token.service.ts#L238) which I assume is not secure and safe. How do I implement this functionality safely? Github desktop does this nicely by triggering my safari browser window and returning to electron app after auth is complete.